# How to set time value from one textbox to another wicked time picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wickedpicker

I need to set the time value in time picker which I'm putting in another text box.
like if I put 10:30 PM in my text box then on button click in another text box which have wicked timepicker in it

```
<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/wickedpicker.css">
<script src="src/wickedpicker.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" id="time"/><br>
<input type="text" class="input" id="time1"/><br>
<input type="button" value="Show" id="btn"/>
```

in jquery I tried this-

```
$("#time").wickedpicker();
$("#btn").click(function(){
var val=$("#time1").val();
$("#time").wickedpicker("setTime",val);
$("#time1").wickedpicker("setTime",val);
alert("selected time is  " + val);
});
```

I did the same with date picker and it worked so I thought it would work with this but its no use even alert is not working, its saying value undefine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code include the modification of wicked picker js in order to change and update picker value.

```js
/**
 * wickedpicker v0.4.1 - A simple jQuery timepicker.
 * Copyright (c) 2015-2016 Eric Gagnon - http://github.com/wickedRidge/wickedpicker
 * License: MIT
 * 
 * Modified to allow changing the time.
 * Example:
 *    var options = {now: "12:35"};
 *    var myPicker = $('.timepicker').wickedpicker(options);
 * 
 *    myPicker.wickedpicker('setTime', 0, "14:00"); // 0 is the index of the timepicker. Use 0 if only one
 */

!function($,window,document){"use strict";"function"!=typeof String.prototype.endsWith&&(String.prototype.endsWith=function(e){return e.length>0&&this.substring(this.length-e.length,this.length)===e});var isMobile=function(){return/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)},today=new Date,pluginName="wickedpicker",defaults={now:today.getHours()+":"+today.getMinutes(),twentyFour:!1,upArrow:"wickedpicker__controls__control-up",downArrow:"wickedpicker__controls__control-down",close:"wickedpicker__close",hoverState:"hover-state",title:"Timepicker",showSeconds:!1,timeSeparator:" : ",secondsInterval:1,minutesInterval:1,beforeShow:null,afterShow:null,show:null,clearable:!1,closeOnClickOutside:!0,onClickOutside:function(){}};function Wickedpicker(e,t){this.element=$(e),this.options=$.extend({},defaults,t),this.element.addClass("hasWickedpicker"),this.element.attr("onkeypress","return false;"),this.element.attr("aria-showingpicker","false"),this.createPicker(),this.timepicker=$(".wickedpicker"),this.up=$("."+this.options.upArrow.split(/\s+/).join(".")),this.down=$("."+this.options.downArrow.split(/\s+/).join(".")),this.separator=$(".wickedpicker__controls__control--separator"),this.hoursElem=$(".wickedpicker__controls__control--hours"),this.minutesElem=$(".wickedpicker__controls__control--minutes"),this.secondsElem=$(".wickedpicker__controls__control--seconds"),this.meridiemElem=$(".wickedpicker__controls__control--meridiem"),this.close=$("."+this.options.close.split(/\s+/).join("."));var i=this.timeArrayFromString(this.options.now);this.options.now=new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate(),i[0],i[1],i[2]),this.selectedHour=this.parseHours(this.options.now.getHours()),this.selectedMin=this.parseSecMin(this.options.now.getMinutes()),this.selectedSec=this.parseSecMin(this.options.now.getSeconds()),this.selectedMeridiem=this.parseMeridiem(this.options.now.getHours()),this.setHoverState(),this.attach(e),this.setText(e)}$.extend(Wickedpicker.prototype,{showPicker:function(e){"function"==typeof this.options.beforeShow&&this.options.beforeShow(e,this.timepicker);var t=$(e).offset();if($(e).attr({"aria-showingpicker":"true",tabindex:-1}),this.setText(e),this.showHideMeridiemControl(),this.getText(e)!==this.getTime()){var i=this.getText(e),s=/\s\w\w$/.test(i)?i.substr(-2,2):null,o=i.replace(/\s\w\w$/,"").split(this.options.timeSeparator),n={};n.hours=o[0],n.minutes=o[1],this.options.showSeconds?(n.seconds=o[2],n.meridiem=s):n.meridiem=s,this.setTime(n)}this.timepicker.css({"z-index":this.element.css("z-index")+1,position:"absolute",left:t.left,top:t.top+$(e)[0].offsetHeight}).show(),"function"==typeof this.options.show&&this.options.show(e,this.timepicker),this.handleTimeAdjustments(e)},hideTimepicker:function(e){var t;this.timepicker.hide(),"function"==typeof this.options.afterShow&&this.options.afterShow(e,this.timepicker),function(){var e=$.Deferred();return $('[aria-showingpicker="true"]').attr("aria-showingpicker","false"),e.promise()}().then((t=0,void setTimeout(function(){$('[aria-showingpicker="false"]').attr("tabindex",t)},400)))},createPicker:function(){if(0===$(".wickedpicker").length){var e='<div class="wickedpicker"><p class="wickedpicker__title">'+this.options.title+'<span class="wickedpicker__close"></span></p><ul class="wickedpicker__controls"><li class="wickedpicker__controls__control"><span class="'+this.options.upArrow+'"></span><span class="wickedpicker__controls__control--hours" tabindex="-1">00</span><span class="'+this.options.downArrow+'"></span></li><li class="wickedpicker__controls__control--separator"><span class="wickedpicker__controls__control--separator-inner">:</span></li><li class="wickedpicker__controls__control"><span class="'+this.options.upArrow+'"></span><span class="wickedpicker__controls__control--minutes" tabindex="-1">00</span><span class="'+this.options.downArrow+'"></span></li>';this.options.showSeconds&&(e+='<li class="wickedpicker__controls__control--separator"><span class="wickedpicker__controls__control--separator-inner">:</span></li><li class="wickedpicker__controls__control"><span class="'+this.options.upArrow+'"></span><span class="wickedpicker__controls__control--seconds" tabindex="-1">00</span><span class="'+this.options.downArrow+'"></span> </li>'),e+='<li class="wickedpicker__controls__control"><span class="'+this.options.upArrow+'"></span><span class="wickedpicker__controls__control--meridiem" tabindex="-1">AM</span><span class="'+this.options.downArrow+'"></span></li></ul></div>',$("body").append(e),this.attachKeyboardEvents()}},showHideMeridiemControl:function(){!1===this.options.twentyFour?$(this.meridiemElem).parent().show():$(this.meridiemElem).parent().hide()},showHideSecondsControl:function(){this.options.showSeconds?$(this.secondsElem).parent().show():$(this.secondsElem).parent().hide()},attach:function(e){var t=this;this.options.clearable&&t.makePickerInputClearable(e),$(e).attr("tabindex",0),$(e).on("click focus",function(e){$(t.timepicker).is(":hidden")&&(t.showPicker($(this)),window.lastTimePickerControl=$(this),$(t.hoursElem).focus())});var i=function(e){if($(t.timepicker).is(":visible")){if($(e.target).is(t.close))t.hideTimepicker(window.lastTimePickerControl);else if($(e.target).closest(t.timepicker).length||$(e.target).closest($(".hasWickedpicker")).length)e.stopPropagation();else{if("function"==typeof t.options.onClickOutside?t.options.onClickOutside():console.warn("Type of onClickOutside must be a function"),!t.options.closeOnClickOutside)return;t.hideTimepicker(window.lastTimePickerControl)}window.lastTimePickerControl=null}};$(document).off("click",i).on("click",i)},attachKeyboardEvents:function(){$(document).on("keydown",$.proxy(function(e){switch(e.keyCode){case 9:"hasWickedpicker"!==e.target.className&&$(this.close).trigger("click");break;case 27:$(this.close).trigger("click");break;case 37:e.target.className!==this.hoursElem[0].className?$(e.target).parent().prevAll("li").not(this.separator.selector).first().children()[1].focus():$(e.target).parent().siblings(":last").children()[1].focus();break;case 39:e.target.className!==this.meridiemElem[0].className?$(e.target).parent().nextAll("li").not(this.separator.selector).first().children()[1].focus():$(e.target).parent().siblings(":first").children()[1].focus();break;case 38:$(":focus").prev().trigger("click");break;case 40:$(":focus").next().trigger("click")}},this))},setTime:function(e){this.setHours(e.hours),this.setMinutes(e.minutes),this.setMeridiem(e.meridiem),this.options.showSeconds&&this.setSeconds(e.seconds)},getTime:function(){return[this.formatTime(this.getHours(),this.getMinutes(),this.getMeridiem(),this.getSeconds())]},setHours:function(e){var t=new Date;t.setHours(e);var i=this.parseHours(t.getHours());this.hoursElem.text(i),this.selectedHour=i},getHours:function(){var e=new Date;return e.setHours(this.hoursElem.text()),e.getHours()},parseHours:function(e){return!1===this.options.twentyFour?(e+11)%12+1:e<10?"0"+e:e},setMinutes:function(e){var t=new Date;t.setMinutes(e);var i=t.getMinutes(),s=this.parseSecMin(i);this.minutesElem.text(s),this.selectedMin=s},getMinutes:function(){var e=new Date;return e.setMinutes(this.minutesElem.text()),e.getMinutes()},parseSecMin:function(e){return(e<10?"0":"")+e},setMeridiem:function(e){var t="";void 0===e?t="PM"===this.getMeridiem()?"AM":"PM":t=e;this.meridiemElem.text(t),this.selectedMeridiem=t},getMeridiem:function(){return this.meridiemElem.text()},setSeconds:function(e){var t=new Date;t.setSeconds(e);var i=t.getSeconds(),s=this.parseSecMin(i);this.secondsElem.text(s),this.selectedSec=s},getSeconds:function(){var e=new Date;return e.setSeconds(this.secondsElem.text()),e.getSeconds()},parseMeridiem:function(e){return e>11?"PM":"AM"},handleTimeAdjustments:function(e){var t=0;$(this.up).add(this.down).off("mousedown click touchstart").on("mousedown click",{Wickedpicker:this,input:e},function(e){if(1!=e.which)return!1;var i=this.className.indexOf("up")>-1?"+":"-",s=e.data;"mousedown"==e.type?t=setInterval($.proxy(function(e){e.Wickedpicker.changeValue(i,e.input,this)},this,{Wickedpicker:s.Wickedpicker,input:s.input}),200):s.Wickedpicker.changeValue(i,s.input,this)}).bind("mouseup touchend",function(){clearInterval(t)})},changeValue:function(operator,input,clicked){var target="+"===operator?clicked.nextSibling:clicked.previousSibling,targetClass=$(target).attr("class");targetClass.endsWith("hours")?this.setHours(eval(this.getHours()+operator+1)):targetClass.endsWith("minutes")?this.setMinutes(eval(this.getMinutes()+operator+this.options.minutesInterval)):targetClass.endsWith("seconds")?this.setSeconds(eval(this.getSeconds()+operator+this.options.secondsInterval)):this.setMeridiem(),this.setText(input)},setText:function(e){$(e).val(this.formatTime(this.selectedHour,this.selectedMin,this.selectedMeridiem,this.selectedSec)).change()},getText:function(e){return $(e).val()},formatTime:function(e,t,i,s){var o=e+this.options.timeSeparator+t;return this.options.twentyFour&&(o=e+this.options.timeSeparator+t),this.options.showSeconds&&(o+=this.options.timeSeparator+s),!1===this.options.twentyFour&&(o+=" "+i),o},setHoverState:function(){var e=this;isMobile()||$(this.up).add(this.down).add(this.close).hover(function(){$(this).toggleClass(e.options.hoverState)})},makePickerInputClearable:function(e){$(e).wrap('<div class="clearable-picker"></div>').after("<span data-clear-picker>&times;</span>"),$("[data-clear-picker]").on("click",function(e){$(this).siblings(".hasWickedpicker").val("")})},timeArrayFromString:function(e){if(e.length){var t=e.split(":");return t[2]=t.length<3?"00":t[2],t}return!1},_time:function(){var e=$(this.element).val();return""===e?this.formatTime(this.selectedHour,this.selectedMin,this.selectedMeridiem,this.selectedSec):e},_setTime:function(e){this.options.now=e;var t=this.timeArrayFromString(this.options.now);this.options.now=new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate(),t[0],t[1],t[2]),this.selectedHour=this.parseHours(this.options.now.getHours()),this.selectedMin=this.parseSecMin(this.options.now.getMinutes()),this.selectedSec=this.parseSecMin(this.options.now.getSeconds()),this.selectedMeridiem=this.parseMeridiem(this.options.now.getHours()),this.setText(this.element);var i=$(this.element).val();return""===i?this.formatTime(this.selectedHour,this.selectedMin,this.selectedMeridiem,this.selectedSec):i},_hide:function(){this.hideTimepicker(this.element)}}),$.fn[pluginName]=function(e,t,i){return $.isFunction(Wickedpicker.prototype["_"+e])?$(this).hasClass("hasWickedpicker")?"setTime"===e?void 0!==t?$.data($(this)[t],"plugin_"+pluginName)._setTime(i):$.data($(this)[0],"plugin_"+pluginName)._setTime(i):void 0!==t?$.data($(this)[t],"plugin_"+pluginName)["_"+e]():$.data($(this)[0],"plugin_"+pluginName)["_"+e]():void 0:this.each(function(){$.data(this,"plugin_"+pluginName)||$.data(this,"plugin_"+pluginName,new Wickedpicker(this,e))})}}(jQuery,window,document);


    $(document).ready(function() {

        var timepicker = $("#time").wickedpicker();
        $("#btn").click(function(){
           var time = timepicker.wickedpicker('time');  
           time = time.replace(' : ', ' ');
           var h = time.split(' ')[0];
           var m = time.split(' ')[1];
           var ampm = time.split(' ')[2];
           if (ampm == 'PM') {
             h = parseInt(h) + 12;
           }
           
          var options2 = {
            now:  h+':'+m,
          };
          var time1 = $("#time1").wickedpicker(options2);
          time1.wickedpicker('setTime',0,  h+':'+m)
        });
        
    });
```

```html
    <link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Minimal-jQuery-Timer-Picker-Plugin-Wickedpicker/stylesheets/wickedpicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="time"/><br>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="time1"/><br>
    <input type="button" value="Show" id="btn"/><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It only works for the first time. When first input value change and after that, you click the button it didn't update the second input value with wickedpicker.

Comment: and its also updating the current time in both of the textboxes but I want the oposite, I want to update user input time value in both

Comment: HI @Angie please check the latest solution which allows the updation of time on multiple clicks

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `wickedpicker('time')` to get time value instead.

2) Convert time in 24 hours format before assigning the time value.

```js
$('#time1').wickedpicker();

$('button').on('click', function() {
  // get time form time1
  var t = ($('#time1').wickedpicker('time'));
  // convert to 24 hours format
  t = t.replace(' : ', ' ');
  var h = t.split(' ')[0];
  var m = t.split(' ')[1];
  var ampm = t.split(' ')[2];
  if (ampm == 'PM') {
    h = parseInt(h) + 12;
  }
  // set time to time2
  $('#time2').wickedpicker({now: h+':'+m});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/wickedpicker@0.4.3/dist/wickedpicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/wickedpicker@0.4.3/dist/wickedpicker.min.js"></script>

Time 1: <input type="text" class="time" id="time1"><br>
Time 2: <input type="text" class="time" id="time2"><br>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: It only works for the first time. When first input value change and after that, you click the button it didn't update the second input value with wickedpicker.

Comment: This is the plugin's limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to set the time (`timeTokens` is array consisting of hour and minute):

```
var setTimePicker = function (timeTokens) {
    $('.wickedpicker__controls__control--hours').text(timeTokens[0]);
    $('.wickedpicker__controls__control--minutes').text(timeTokens[1]);
    wickedpicker.data('plugin_wickedpicker').selectedHour = timeTokens[0];
    wickedpicker.data('plugin_wickedpicker').selectedMin = timeTokens[1];
}
```